# Updating a graph on change of data in d3.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-scope, angular-services

hi I am using the following code to basically create a bar graph by consuming data from a service call. The problem with this is as the data from the service call changes, it is not reflected in the bar graph, it remains in its original state. The Appname and Appcount are two things which i am getting from the service call

```
jQuery(function($) 
{
Appnames = []//array will be populated from service call,
  Appcount = []//array will be populated from serv`enter code here`ice call,
  chart,
  width = 700,
  bar_height = 40,
  gap = 2,
  height = bar_height * Appnames.length;
  var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120};

  /* step 1 - create the background*/
  chart = d3.select($("#step-1")[0])
.append('svg')
.attr('class', 'chart')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height);

  /* step 2 - create the bars*/
  var x, y;

 chart = d3.select($("#step-2")[0])
.append('svg')
.attr('class', 'chart')
.attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
.attr('height', height);

 x = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(Appcount)])
 .range([0, width]);

 y = function(i) { return bar_height * i; }

 chart.selectAll("rect")
 .data(Appcount)
 .enter().append("rect")
 .attr("x", 0)
 .attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(i);})
 .attr("width", x)
 .attr("height", bar_height);

  /* step 3 - add counts to the bars*/
chart = d3.select($("#step-3")[0])
.append('svg')
.attr('class', 'chart')
.attr('width', width)
.attr('height', height);

 chart.selectAll("rect")
.data(Appcount)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(i);})
.attr("width", x)
.attr("height", bar_height);

 chart.selectAll("text")
.data(Appcount)
.enter().append("text")
.attr("x", x)
.attr("y", function(d, i){ return y(i) + bar_height/2; } )
.attr("dx", -5)
.attr("dy", ".36em")
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.text(String);

 /* step 4 - add Appnames to bars*/
 var left_width = 100;

chart = d3.select($("#step-4")[0])
.append('svg')
.attr('class', 'chart')
.attr('width', left_width + width)
.attr('height', height);

chart.selectAll("rect")
.data(Appcount)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("x", left_width)
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(i);})
.attr("width", x)
.attr("height", bar_height);

chart.selectAll("text.score")
.data(Appcount)
.enter().append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) + left_width; })
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(i) + bar_height / 2;})
.attr("dx", -5)
.attr("dy", ".36em")
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.attr('class', 'score')
.text(String);

 chart.selectAll("text.name")
.data(Appnames)
.enter().append("text")
.attr("x", left_width / 2)
.attr("y", function(d, i){ return y(i) +bar_height/2; } )
.attr("dy", ".36em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr('class', 'name')
.text(String);

 /* step 5 - add a ruler line to the bars*/
 var gap = 2, yRangeBand;
// redefine y for adjusting the gap
yRangeBand = bar_height + 2 * gap;
y = function(i) { return yRangeBand * i; };

chart = d3.select($("#step-5")[0])
.append('svg')
.attr('class', 'chart')
.attr('width', left_width + width + 40)
.attr('height', (bar_height + gap * 2) * Appnames.length + 30)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(10, 20)");

chart.selectAll("line")
.data(x.ticks(d3.max(Appcount)))
.enter().append("line")
.attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d) + left_width; })
.attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d) + left_width; })
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("y2", (bar_height + gap * 2) * Appnames.length);

chart.selectAll(".rule")
.data(x.ticks(d3.max(Appcount)))
.enter().append("text")
.attr("class", "rule")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) + left_width; })
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("dy", -6)
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr("font-size", 10)
.text(String);

 chart.selectAll("rect")
.data(Appcount)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("x", left_width)
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(i) + gap; })
.attr("width", x)
.attr("height", bar_height);

 chart.selectAll("text.score")
.data(Appcount)
.enter().append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) + left_width; })
.attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(i) + yRangeBand/2;})
.attr("dx", -5)
.attr("dy", ".36em")
.attr("text-anchor", "end")
.attr('class', 'score')
.text(String);

 chart.selectAll("text.name")
.data(Appnames)
.enter().append("text")
.attr("x", left_width / 2)
.attr("y", function(d, i){ return y(i) + yRangeBand/2; } )
.attr("dy", ".36em")
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.attr('class', 'name')
.text(String); }(jQuery));
```

Comment: (jQuery)) with angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3 uses an [enter, update and exit pattern](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).  Your code is only handling the `enter` state.  Split it up to handle all 3 states:

```
var rects = chart.selectAll("rect")
  .data(Appcount); //<-- create your data join

rects.enter().append("rect"); //<-- ENTER - when data enters the join append a rect element to dom

rects.exit().remove(); //<-- EXIT - when data leaves the join, remove the rect

rects.attr("x", 0) //<-- UPDATE - update the rects based on data
  .attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(i);})
  .attr("width", x)
  .attr("height", bar_height);
```